# Django - Can a query update delete an existing record?

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

In my views.py I have something like this:

```
 a = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
 a.avatar = avatar.id
 a.save()
```

From what I know when I do a save() if there is already a record with that specific user id it should just update the existing record with the avatar.id.

I'm not sure why but when I run the above code the existing record gets deleted. Am I doing this right?

Comment: .save() should update, not delete

Comment: save() can not delete unless it is overridden or there is something else going on. Does the code above delete the record if you try it from the interactive shell (manage.py shell)?

Comment: @julio.alegria avatar is a field where I store the id number for the user avatar. In other words it's an integer field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that **the answer is NO**.

I used `manage.py shell` and ran the above code and it didn't not delete the record. But I found out that another code above it was doing the damage.

I had something like this:

```
avatar = Avatar.objects.create(user = a_user)
avatar.delete()
```

The Profile model has a foreign key relationship with the Avatar. So when I did avatar.delete() when I thought it only deleted the record for the Avatar model it also deleted related Profile record.